# Create a filtered copy of JavaScript object with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm new to JavaScript/jQuery and there's probably an easy way to do this, but I'm unable to find the function or syntax I need. Basically, I have a set of objects like this:

```
{
  "Object1": [
    {
      "Value": "ABC",
      "IsEnabled": true
    },
    {
      "Value": "DEF",
      "IsEnabled": false
    }
  ],
  "Object2": [
    {
      "Value": "GHI",
      "IsEnabled": false
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to turn it into a new set of objects based on the "IsEnabled" value equals true.

```
{
  "Object1": [
    {
      "Value": "ABC",
      "IsEnabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

If it's simpler, I would also be OK with not a new object, but the existing object with the "IsEnabled"=false objects removed. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the `filter()` method do what you want?

Comment: It probably does, but I don't understand the syntax I need to loop through each Object in my set of objects, and filter out the array inside each Object based on IsEnabled. Everything I tried either threw an error or returned undefined.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the attempts you've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in for a *functional programming* pattern, you can for instance use `Object.entries`, then `map` and `filter` on that array of pairs, and finally `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let obj = {"Object1": [{"Value": "ABC","IsEnabled": true},{"Value": "DEF","IsEnabled": false}],"Object2": [{"Value": "GHI","IsEnabled": false}]};

let result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
          .map(([k, arr]) => [k, arr.filter(o => o.IsEnabled)])
          .filter(([, arr]) => arr.length)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the properties in the outer object. For each of them, call `filter()` to get just the enabled objects in the array. If the resulting array is not empty, add it to the result.

```js
const input = {
  "Object1": [
    {
      "Value": "ABC",
      "IsEnabled": true
    },
    {
      "Value": "DEF",
      "IsEnabled": false
    }
  ],
  "Object2": [
    {
      "Value": "GHI",
      "IsEnabled": false
    }
  ]
};

const output = {};

Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, array]) => {
  const new_array = array.filter(el => el.IsEnabled);
  if (new_array.length > 0) {
    output[key] = new_array;
  }
});

console.log(output);
```